# Do you plan on using the Factor programming language?

Tags: factor-lang

Do you plan on using [Factor](http://factorcode.org/)? Have you looked at it?  Checked it out. Do you understand stack oriented programming?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_0QlhYlS8g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factor looks interesting, but it badly needs more introductory tutorials and articles.

Comment: I'm trying to address that http://factor.openeducationtools.com/

Answer (score 26):

fun for aside language based stack a in point the see don't I but, Forth resembles it and briefly Factor studied I.

Comment: I see what you did thar.

Comment: "People talking in postfix notation" "end of the world" =

Answer (score 6):

I intend to learn it after finishing my Clojure learning adventures.

UPDATE:

After many moons, I've been using Factor for some stuff lately, and I'll say it's an amazing language. The only issue is the still-standing issue related to very little in the way of GUI tools. The Factor UI toolkit is seriously lacking a lot of common things, and there are no bindings to any toolkit in existence as of this writing. This would probably be a deal breaker for any real-world desktop application.

Comment: It's been over a year since your update. What are your current thoughts on Factor?

Comment: I think Factor is a great language. The problem I had with GUI toolkits had recently been mostly solved with the addition of GTK bindings. I just wish it was more vocal about it's activities. It needs more people to be interested in it for it to get anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

I have been using Factor for a few months, and it is really an impressive language.

It feels like a blend of Forth (obviously), Smalltalk (image-based, highly reflective, "integrated" IDE), and LISP (code-as-data, syntax-level abstractions, REPL).. and to some extent, languages such as Python or Ruby, with a strong emphasis on pragmatism and openess (eg. "batteries included").

Moreover the performance seems to be important for the designers, as a lot of work have been spent on the optimizing compiler, much like the SBCL implementation of Common Lisp.

The project still suffers a bit from his youngness, with some frequent language changes, parts of the system underdocumented, and a relatively small community. But even at this stage, I think it feels mature enough to start some non trivial stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I can't talk about factor specifically, but I have done a lot with HP Calculators.  The stack-based RPN language it comes with is quite sophisticated.  A ton of software has been written for these calculators.

http://www.hpcalc.org/

Answer (score 3):

I am considering using Factor for my next big non-work project. I was trying to choose between Factor, OCaml, D and Python. Normally, Python is my language of choice, but for this I'm looking for something different. I was considering D (I used C++ for a good many years and wanted to use D as a cleaner C++), but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for really.

That leaves OCaml and Factor and I'm having a tough time deciding. OCaml would be slightly easier for me to get to grips with, as my concatenative programming is a bit rusty and I also quite like the language a lot, but Factor keeps drawing me in too (and I'm a big fan of concatenative languages). Hrm indecision..

UPDATE:
I have since decided to learn Factor properly and use it for my upcoming large personal project. In the meantime, I am working on some of the problems from [Programming Challenges](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387001638) in Factor.

UPDATE 2:
Factor didn't quite cut it.. Not because of the language, the language is great and I recommend everyone to take a look at it. The reason was Qt bindings. This was an important deal breaker for me. I would bind Qt myself and contribute it, but then I have two projects instead of one and I simply don't have the time. So, sorry Factor. I wrote the code in C++ instead, but I'm now considering either porting it to Clojure or writing future code in Clojure.

Comment: I didn't like Clojure very much when I looked at it. Then again, I only glanced at it really, so I guess my evaluation was less than fair.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I took another look at Clojure since and... I love it! You were totally right, its a great language and theres a good chance I'll be suing it for my projects now. :-P

Comment: Admittedly, you told me that all along.. maybe I should have listened ;-) But yes - yes it does! 1.1 is niiiice and Rich is doing a brilliant job. Also looking forward to Chouser's book.